# conflict with fortran compiler and c++ libraries

Tags: c++, fortran, libraries

I really need your help, I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days now with no luck. I am compiling with gfortran (as the main program is in fortran) a program which calls for a library installed (lhapdf) in the standard directory, it is actually found but when linking with c++ libraries it appears to have a problem. As I have no familiarity with configure and makefiles I cant figure out what is wrong, this is my configure file:

```
    #! /bin/sh
    # configure script for FormCalc
    # note: has nothing to do with GNU autoconf
    # this file is part of FormCalc
# last modified 30 Aug 14 th


exec 2> ${LOGFILE:-/dev/null} 3>&1
eval ${LOGFILE:+set -x}


LC_ALL=C
export LC_ALL

test=test$$
trap "rm -fr $test*" 0 1 2 3 15

if (echo "test\c"; echo 1,2,3) | grep c > /dev/null ; then
  if (echo -n test; echo 1,2,3) | grep n > /dev/null ; then
    echo_n=
    echo_c='
'
  else
    echo_n=-n
    echo_c=
  fi
else
  echo_n=
  echo_c='\c'
fi


findprog() {
  echo $echo_n "looking for $1... $echo_c" 1>&3
  shift
  test -n "$CONF_TARGET" && for prog in "$@" ; do
    full="`which \"$CONF_TARGET-$prog\" 2> /dev/null`"
    test -x "$full" && {
      echo $full 1>&3
      echo $CONF_TARGET-$prog
      return 0
    }
  done
  for prog in "$@" ; do
    full="`which \"$prog\" 2> /dev/null`"
    test -x "$full" && {
      echo $full 1>&3
      echo $prog
      return 0
    }
  done
  echo "no $@ in your path" 1>&3
  return 1
}


findlib() {
  echo $echo_n "looking for $1... $echo_c" 1>&3
  file=$2
  tag=$3
  shift 3
  for base in "$@" \
    ../$tag* \
    ../../$tag* \
    ../../../$tag* \
    ../../../../$tag* \
    $HOME/$tag* \
    /usr/local/$tag* \
    /usr/$tag* \
    /usr/local \
    /usr
  do
    for path in \
      "${CONF_LIBDIRSUFFIX:+$base/lib$CONF_LIBDIRSUFFIX}" \
      "${CONF_LIBDIRSUFFIX:+$base/$CONF_DEFPREFIX/lib$CONF_LIBDIRSUFFIX}" \
      "$base/lib" \
      "$base/$CONF_DEFPREFIX/lib" \
      ${CONF_QUAD:+"$base/build-quad"} \
      "$base/build" \
      "$base/includects" \
      "$base/libs" \
      "$base/.libs" \
      "$base/src" \
      "$base/src/.libs" \
      "$base"
    do
      test -f "$path/$file" && {
        echo "$path" 1>&3
        echo "$path"
        return 0
      }
    done
  done
  echo "not found" 1>&3
  return 1
}


getldflags() {
  ldflags="$LDFLAGS"

  while read line ; do
    set -- `echo $line | tr ':,()' '    '`
    case $1 in
    */collect2$CONF_EXE | */ld$CONF_EXE | ld$CONF_EXE) ;;
    *) continue ;;
    esac
    while test $# -gt 1 ; do
      shift
      case $1 in
#      *.o | -lc | -lgcc*)
      *.o | -lc)
        ;;
      -l* | -L* | *.a)
        ldflags="$ldflags $1" ;;
      -Bstatic | -Bdynamic | *.ld)
        ldflags="$ldflags -Wl,$1" ;;
      /*)
        ldflags="$ldflags -L,$1" ;;
      -rpath*)
        ldflags="$ldflags -Wl,$1,$2"
        shift ;;
      -dynamic-linker)
        shift ;;
      esac
    done
  done

  echo $ldflags
}


CONF_SRC=`dirname $0`
CONF_OS=`uname -s`
CONF_OSVER=`uname -r`
CONF_MACH=`uname -m`
CONF_DEFPREFIX="$CONF_MACH-$CONF_OS"
CONF_PREFIX="$CONF_DEFPREFIX"
CONF_TARGET=
CONF_STATIC=
CONF_STATIC_EXT=
CONF_QUAD=
CONF_DEBUG=
CONF_BITS=
  # Mma 5.1's mcc needs -lpthread for static linking
CONF_MCLIBS="-lpthread"
CONF_ARCH="-march=native"
CONF_AS=
CONF_EXE=
case "$CONF_OS" in
CYG*)   CONF_EXE=.exe ;;
Darwin) CONF_AS="-Wa,-q" ;;
esac

CONF_MAKEARGS=0

for arg in "$@" ; do
  case "$arg" in
  --prefix=*)
    CONF_PREFIX=`expr "$arg" : ".*--prefix=\(.*\)"` ;;
  --host=*)
    CONF_TARGET=`expr "$arg" : ".*--host=\(.*\)"` ;;
  --static)
    CONF_STATIC="-static"
    case "$CONF_OS" in
# Apple discourages static linking, see
# http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2001/qa1118.html,
# so we make only libgcc static.  For a static libg2c do:
# sudo chmod 000 /usr/local/lib/libg2c.dylib
    Darwin | CYG*)
        CONF_STATIC_EXT=$CONF_STATIC
        CONF_STATIC= ;;
    esac ;;
  --quad)
    CONF_QUAD=1 ;;
  --debug)
    CONF_DEBUG="-O0 -g" ;;
  --32)
    CONF_BITS=32 ;;
  --64)
    CONF_BITS=64 ;;
  --generic)
    CONF_ARCH=
    CONF_AS= ;;
  --make*)
    CONF_MAKEARGS="`expr "$arg" : "--make=\(.*\)"`" ;;
  --help)
    cat << _EOF_ 1>&3
$0 configures FormCalc-generated Fortran code, i.e. determines
or guesses the compiler and flags and writes out a makefile.

$0 understands the following options:

--prefix=DIR        use DIR as installation directory,

--host=HOST         target host triplet, e.g. i386-pc-linux,

--static            link the executables statically,

--quad              compile with quadruple precision (gfortran 4.6+, ifort and xlf only),

--debug             compile without optimization,

--32                force 32-bit compilation,

--64                force 64-bit compilation,

--generic           do not specifically target the CPU configure runs on,

--make[=ARGS]       immediately continue with "make ARGS" after configure.

_EOF_
    exit 1 ;;
  -*)
    echo "Warning: $arg is not a valid option." 1>&3 ;;
  *=*)
    eval `echo $arg\" | sed 's/=/="/'` ;;
  *)
    echo "Warning: $arg is not a valid argument." 1>&3 ;;
  esac
done

test "$CONF_OS" = Linux -a "$CONF_BITS" \!= 32 && CONF_LIBDIRSUFFIX=64

CONF_M=${CONF_BITS:+-m$CONF_BITS}


## look for some programs

CONF_MAKE=`findprog make $MAKE gmake Make make` || exit 1

CONF_CC=`findprog gcc $CC clang gcc` || exit 1

CONF_CXX=`findprog g++ $CXX clang++ g++` || exit 1

CONF_FC=`findprog fortran $FC ${CONF_QUAD:+ifort gfortran xlf} ifort pgf90 xlf gfortran g95 f90` || exit 1

CONF_AR=`findprog ar $AR ar`

CONF_RANLIB=`findprog ranlib $RANLIB ranlib`

CONF_NM=`findprog nm $NM nm`

CONF_DLLTOOL=`findprog dlltool $DLLTOOL dlltool`

CONF_DEF="-D"

case "`$CONF_FC --version -c 2>&1`" in
*G95*)
  CONF_FFLAGS="$FFLAGS -O0 -g  -ffixed-line-length-132 -freal-loops $CONF_M $CONF_STATIC ${CONF_DEBUG:+-Wall}" ;;
*GNU*)
  CONF_FFLAGS="$FFLAGS ${CONF_DEBUG:--O3 -g} -lLHAPDF -ffixed-line-length-none $CONF_M $CONF_STATIC ${CONF_DEBUG:+-Wall}"
  case "$CONF_FC" in
  *gfortran*)
    CONF_FFLAGS="$CONF_FFLAGS $CONF_ARCH $CONF_AS ${CONF_DEBUG:+-Wtabs -ffpe-trap=invalid,overflow,zero} -ff2c ${CONF_STATIC_EXT:+-static-libgfortran -static-libgcc} ${CONF_QUAD:+-fdefault-real-8}" ;;
  esac ;;
*)
  CONF_FFLAGS="${FFLAGS-default}"
  test "$CONF_FFLAGS" = default && case "$CONF_FC$CONF_MACH" in
  *pgf*)
    CONF_FFLAGS="${CONF_DEBUG:--O3 -g} ${CONF_ARCH:+-Mvect=simd} ${CONF_DEBUG:+-Ktrap=fp} -Mextend -Minform=inform -g77libs ${CONF_STATIC:+-Bstatic} $CONF_M" ;;
  *ifort*)
    CONF_FFLAGS="${CONF_DEBUG:--O3 -g} $CONF_ARCH -extend_source -warn nouncalled -warn truncated_source -assume bscc $CONF_STATIC ${CONF_STATIC_EXT:+-static-intel} ${CONF_QUAD:+-r16 -DDBLE=QEXT -DDIMAG=QIMAG -DDCONJG=QCONJG -DDCMPLX=QCMPLX} $CONF_M" ;;
  *alpha)
    CONF_FFLAGS="${CONF_DEBUG:--O3 -g3} ${CONF_DEBUG:+-fpe0} -extend_source -warn truncated_source ${CONF_STATIC:+-non_shared}" ;;
  *sun* | *sparc*)
    CONF_FFLAGS="${CONF_DEBUG:--O3 -g} ${CONF_DEBUG:+-ftrap=common} -e ${CONF_STATIC:+-Bstatic}" ;;
  *hp*)
    CONF_FFLAGS="${CONF_DEBUG:--O2 -g} ${CONF_DEBUG:++FPVZO} +es +U77 ${CONF_STATIC:+-Wl,-noshared}" ;;
  *xlf*)
    CONF_FFLAGS="${CONF_DEBUG:--O2 -g} ${CONF_DEBUG:+-qflttrap=enable:invalid:overflow:zerodivide} -qfixed=132 -qmaxmem=-1 -qextname ${CONF_QUAD:+-qautodbl=dbl}"
    CONF_DEF="-WF,-D" ;;
  *)
    CONF_FFLAGS="${CONF_DEBUG:--O -g}" ;;
  esac ;;
esac


## find the Fortran libraries

echo $echo_n "extracting the Fortran libraries... $echo_c" 1>&3

rm -fr $test*

cat > $test.f << _EOF_
    program dontpanic
    print *, "Hi"
    end
_EOF_
eval ${LOGFILE:+cat $test.f 1>&2}

CONF_LDFLAGS=`$CONF_FC $CONF_FFLAGS -v -o -lstdc++ $test $test.f 2>&1 | getldflags`

CONF_INCPATH="$INCPATH"
CONF_STDLIBS="$STDLIBS"
case "$CONF_OS$CONF_OSVER" in
Darwin10*) CONF_STDLIBS="${CONF_STDLIBS:+$CONF_STDLIBS }-lSystemStubs" ;;
esac

echo $CONF_LDFLAGS 1>&3


test -z "$CONF_BITS" && case "$CONF_MACH" in
*86*)   CONF_BITS=32
    case "`file $test`" in
    *x86?64*) CONF_BITS=64 ;;
    esac
    CONF_M="-m$CONF_BITS" ;;
esac


CONF_CFLAGS="${CFLAGS-${CONF_DEBUG:--O3 -g } $CONF_ARCH -std=gnu99 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math} $CONF_M $CONF_STATIC ${CONF_STATIC_EXT:+-static-libgcc}"

CONF_CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS $CONF_M $CONF_STATIC ${CONF_STATIC_EXT:+-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc}"


## does Fortran need externals for U77 routines?

echo $echo_n "does $CONF_FC need externals for U77 routines... $echo_c" 1>&3

rm -fr $test*

cat > $test.f << _EOF_
    program test
    implicit none
    print *, iargc(), len_trim("Hi")
    end
_EOF_
eval ${LOGFILE:+cat $test.f 1>&2}

if $CONF_FC $CONF_FFLAGS -c $test.f 1>&2 ; then
  echo "no" 1>&3
  CONF_U77EXT=0
else
  echo "yes" 1>&3
  CONF_U77EXT=1
fi


## does Fortran append underscores to symbols?

echo $echo_n "does $CONF_FC append underscores... $echo_c" 1>&3

rm -fr $test*

echo "void uscore$$_() {}" > $test-c.c
eval ${LOGFILE:+cat $test-c.c 1>&2}

cat > $test.f << _EOF_
    program test_uscore
    call uscore$$
    end
_EOF_
eval ${LOGFILE:+cat $test.f 1>&2}

$CONF_CC $CONF_CFLAGS -c $test-c.c 1>&2

if $CONF_FC $CONF_FFLAGS -o $test $test.f $test-c.o 1>&2 ; then
  echo "yes" 1>&3
else
  echo "no" 1>&3
  CONF_CFLAGS="$CONF_CFLAGS -DNOUNDERSCORE"
fi


## find max SIMD vector length supported by hardware

echo $echo_n "extracting SIMD capabilities of $CONF_FC... $echo_c" 1>&3

cat simd.h - > $test.F << _EOF_ 2> /dev/null
#ifdef GENERIC
#define SIMD2 0
#define PROP "none"
#elif defined __AVX__
#define SIMD2 2
#define PROP "AVX"
#elif defined __SSE3__
#define SIMD2 1
#define PROP "SSE3"
#else
#define SIMD2 0
#define PROP "none"
#endif

    program test
    print *, PROP
#if defined SIMD && SIMD == SIMD2
#else
    print *, SIMD2
#endif
    end
_EOF_
eval ${LOGFILE:+cat $test.F 1>&2}

$CONF_FC $CONF_FFLAGS ${CONF_ARCH:-${CONF_DEF}GENERIC} -o $test $test.F 1>&2
set -- `./$test 2>&1`
echo $1 1>&3
case $2 in
0|1|2)  cat > simd.h << _EOF_
#if 0
    vectorization ability of $CONF_FC on $HOSTNAME
    determined by $0 on `date`
#endif

#define SIMD $2

_EOF_
    ;;
esac


# check for the necessary libraries

CONF_LIBS=

LTLIB=libooptools${CONF_QUAD:+-quad}.a

CONF_LT="`findlib LoopTools $LTLIB LoopTools $LT`" && {
  CONF_INCPATH="${CONF_INCPATH:+$CONF_INCPATH:}\$(LT)/../include:\$(LT)"
  CONF_LIBS="\$(LT)/$LTLIB"
}

CONF_NINJA="`findlib Ninja libninja.a ninja $NINJA`" && {
  echo $echo_n "determining C++ library needed by Ninja... $echo_c" 1>&3
  cat > $test.f << _EOF_
    program test
    call ninjaformcalc
    end
_EOF_
  eval ${LOGFILE:+cat $test.f 1>&2}
  LIBCPP=-lstdc++
  $CONF_FC $CONF_FFLAGS -o $test $test.f $CONF_NINJA/libninja.a $CONF_LT/$LTLIB \
    $LIBCPP $CONF_STDLIBS 1>&2 || LIBCPP=-lc++
  echo "$LIBCPP" 1>&3
  CONF_LIBS="\$(NINJA)/libninja.a $LIBCPP${CONF_LIBS:+ $CONF_LIBS}"
}

CONF_SAMURAI="`findlib Samurai libsamurai.a samurai $SAMURAI`" && {
  CONF_INCPATH="${CONF_INCPATH:+$CONF_INCPATH:}\$(SAMURAI)/../samurai:\$(SAMURAI)"
  CONF_LIBS="\$(SAMURAI)/libsamurai.a \$(SAMURAI)/libqcdloop.a `\$(SAMURAI)/libavh_olo.a${CONF_LIBS:+ $CONF_LIBS}"
}

CONF_CT="`findlib CutTools libcts.a Cuttools $CT`" && {
  CONF_INCPATH="${CONF_INCPATH:+$CONF_INCPATH:}\$(CT)"
  CONF_LIBS="\$(CT)/libcts.a${CONF_LIBS:+ $CONF_LIBS}"
}

CONF_FH="`findlib FeynHiggs libFH.a FeynHiggs $FH`" && {
  CONF_INCPATH="${CONF_INCPATH:+$CONF_INCPATH:}\$(FH)/../include:\$(FH)"
  CONF_LIBS="\$(FH)/libFH.a${CONF_LIBS:+ $CONF_LIBS}"
}

CONF_LHAPDF="`findlib LHAPDF libLHAPDF.a lhapdf $LHAPDF`" &&
  CONF_LIBS="\$(LHAPDF)/libLHAPDF.a${CONF_LIBS:+ $CONF_LIBS}"


echo "creating makefile" 1>&3

cat - `dirname $0`/makefile.in > makefile << _EOF_
# --- variables defined by configure ---

SRC = $CONF_SRC
PREFIX = $CONF_PREFIX
LIBDIRSUFFIX = $CONF_LIBDIRSUFFIX

EXE = $CONF_EXE
DEF = $CONF_DEF

LT = $CONF_LT
NINJA = $CONF_NINJA
SAMURAI = $CONF_SAMURAI
CT = $CONF_CT
FH = $CONF_FH
LHAPDF = $CONF_LHAPDF
INCPATH = $CONF_INCPATH
STDLIBS = $CONF_LIBS $CONF_STDLIBS
LDFLAGS = $CONF_LDFLAGS

FC = $CONF_FC
FFLAGS = $CONF_FFLAGS \$(DEF)U77EXT=$CONF_U77EXT ${CONF_DEBUG:+\$(DEF)DEBUG}

CC = $CONF_CC
CFLAGS = $CONF_CFLAGS

CXX = $CONF_CXX
CXXFLAGS = $CONF_CXXFLAGS

MCFLAGS = ${CONF_STATIC:+-st} ${CONF_STATIC_EXT:+-st} ${CONF_BITS:+-b$CONF_BITS}
MCLIBS = $CONF_MCLIBS

# --- end defs by configure ---


_EOF_

if test "$CONF_MAKEARGS" = 0 ; then
  cat << _EOF_ 1>&3

now you must run $CONF_MAKE

_EOF_
else
  $CONF_MAKE $CONF_MAKEARGS 1>&3 2>&3
fi

exit 0
```

After running make these are the errors:

```
gfortran -O3 -g -lLHAPDF -ffixed-line-length-none    -march=native   -ff2c   -DU77EXT=0  -I. -I./F -I. -I. -I../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/../include -I../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64 -I/usr/local/lib64/../include -I/usr/local/lib64 -Irenconst/ -DPREFIX= -o run run.F  renconst.a squaredme.a util.a /usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a /usr/local/lib64/libFH.a ../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a 
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `getprefixpath_':
/home/vannia/Documents/lhapdf-5.9.1/src/getdatapath.cc:28: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2405: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::append(char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:1009: undefined reference to `std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::assign(char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:1131: undefined reference to `std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `~basic_string':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `getindexpath_':
/home/vannia/Documents/lhapdf-5.9.1/src/getdatapath.cc:55: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/vannia/Documents/lhapdf-5.9.1/src/getdatapath.cc:55: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::append(char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:1009: undefined reference to `std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:1009: undefined reference to `std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `~basic_string':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `~basic_string':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `getdatapath_':
/home/vannia/Documents/lhapdf-5.9.1/src/getdatapath.cc:77: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2405: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::append(char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:1009: undefined reference to `std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2405: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::append(char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:1009: undefined reference to `std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `getdatapath_':
/home/vannia/Documents/lhapdf-5.9.1/src/getdatapath.cc:82: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2405: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::append(char const*)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:1009: undefined reference to `std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::operator=(std::string const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:547: undefined reference to `std::string::assign(std::string const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `~basic_string':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(getdatapath.o):(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(version.o): In function `getlhapdfversion_':
/home/vannia/Documents/lhapdf-5.9.1/src/version.cc:18: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(version.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(commoninit.o): In function `commoninit_':
commoninit.f:(.text+0x33): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `lhapdf_' defined in COMMON section in /usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(commoninit.o)
commoninit.f:(.text+0x1d1): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `lhaglsta_' defined in COMMON section in /usr/local/lib/libLHAPDF.a(commoninit.o)
../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a(Aget.o): In function `ljacoeff_':
/home/vannia/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/LoopTools-2.9/build/Aget.F:110:(.text+0x1e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ltvars_' defined in COMMON section in ../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a(Aget.o)
/home/vannia/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/LoopTools-2.9/build/Aget.F:112:(.text+0x27): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ltvars_' defined in COMMON section in ../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a(Aget.o)
/home/vannia/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/LoopTools-2.9/build/Aget.F:112:(.text+0x30): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ltvars_' defined in COMMON section in ../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a(Aget.o)
/home/vannia/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/LoopTools-2.9/build/Aget.F:114:(.text+0x3c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ltvars_' defined in COMMON section in ../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a(Aget.o)
/home/vannia/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/LoopTools-2.9/build/Aget.F:114:(.text+0x45): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ltvars_' defined in COMMON section in ../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a(Aget.o)
/home/vannia/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/LoopTools-2.9/build/Aget.F:114:(.text+0x4d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ltvars_' defined in COMMON section in ../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a(Aget.o)
/home/vannia/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/LoopTools-2.9/build/Aget.F:120:(.text+0x84): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ltvars_' defined in COMMON section in ../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a(Aget.o)
/home/vannia/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/LoopTools-2.9/build/Aget.F:125:(.text+0xd3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ltregul_' defined in COMMON section in ../../LoopTools/x86_64-Linux/lib64/libooptools.a(Aget.o)
/home/vannia/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics/LoopTools-2.9/build/Aget.F:125:(.text+0xf0): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Comment: You want to add `-lstdc++` to your command, but your script is too complex for me to find where to change it.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, I actually tried but I do not know where to put it, it is complex to me too. This configure file is created automatically from another software, and the developer suggests to add -lstdc++ to the ldflags for proper linking. Do you know ehere exactly should I modify the ldflags? to include -lstdc++ ?

Answer (score 0):

put it in the makefile in the FFLAGS

```
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS =  -O3 -g -ffixed-line-length-none    -march=native   -ff2c   $(DEF)U77EXT=0 -lstdc++
```

Comment: Thank you Paul Lo, could you please explain me more?